# modified preorder tree: selecting top elements of specific type

Tags: mysql, database, preorder

I use modified preorder tree to store GEO locations in my application in a single table LOC_TABLE. An example of subtree for e.g. Greece looks something like this:

```
+-------+---------------+-----+-----+------+
| ID    | NAME          | LFT | RGT | TYPE |
+-------+---------------+-----+-----+------+
|    10 | Greece        | 100 | 200 |   3  |
|    20 | Crete Isl.    | 120 | 140 |   4  |
|    25 | Crete-Vamos   | 121 | 122 |   4  |
|    26 | Crete-Rethymno| 123 | 124 |   4  |
 ....
+-------+---------------+-----+-----+------+
```

`TYPE` column is used to store type of location (3 - country, 4 - city). As you can see Crete is stored as city, which contains other cities (e.g., `Vamos` and `Rethymno`) as its children.

I'm required to perform two types of queries:

1) Fetch all locations of specific type under specific parent.

2) Fetch all top locations of specific type under specific parent: for provided example of locations only `Crete Isl.` should be returned when querying for cities inside Greece, because `Crete Isl.` doesn't have parents of type city, while cities `Vamos` and `Rethymno` have parent of type city - `Crete Isl.`

What are the fastest queries to perform in each case?

For the first case I consider either using two queries (first, get LFT and RGT of Greece, second to fetch all locations of type = 4, which have appropriate LFT and RGT) or using some kind of join to get all locations in one step. Which is the best approach?

For the second case I don't have any suitable idea currently. I tried simple sub-select:

```
select loc.* from LOC_TABLE loc 
where 4 not in 
(select TYPE from LOC_TABLE p 
    where p.lft < loc.lft AND p.rgt > loc.rgt) 
AND loc.LFT > 100 AND loc.RGT < 200;
```

But it's too long.

I don't mind adding more columns and populating them with some values which will help to speed up these two types of queries. But I need to fetch the data quickly.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For all records that are cities and descendants of a specific record with an `ID` given by `:id`, use

```
SELECT descendant.ID, descendant.NAME, descendant.TYPE 
FROM LOC_TABLE location
INNER JOIN LOC_TABLE descendant
    ON descendant.LFT > location.LFT AND descendant.RGT < location.RGT
WHERE location.ID = :id AND TYPE = 4
```

For all records that are cities and child of a record with an `ID` givien by `:id`, use

```
SELECT child.ID, child.NAME, child.TYPE 
FROM LOC_TABLE location
INNER JOIN LOC_TABLE child
    ON child.LFT > location.LFT AND child.RGT < location.RGT
LEFT OUTER JOIN LOC_TABLE intermediate
    ON intermediate.LFT < child.LFT
    AND intermediate.RGT > child.RGT
    AND intermediate.LFT > location.LFT
    AND intermediate.RGT < location.RGT
WHERE location.ID = :id
AND child.TYPE = 4
AND intermediate.ID IS NULL
```

The `LEFT OUTER JOIN` along with the condition `intermediate.ID IS NULL` eliminates those `child` records, for which there is a decendant of `location` that is ancestor of `child`.

Comment: First query works, but takes ~1.5 seconds to fetch locations. When performing query in 2 steps: fetching LFT and RGT for parent takes less than 0.01 s, fetching locations with LFT > parent.LFT and RGT < parent.RGT takes ~0.2 s. So overall two steps perform faster (I doubt that server round-trip will take as much as 1.3 seconds to equalize these two approaches).

Comment: Second query also work but takes 3-6 seconds. Can we get locations faster? I don't mind adding columns with some cached values to make it faster.

Comment: First, make sure that you have indizes on `ID`, `LFT` and `RGT`. If you have, for the first query, moving the conditions from the `WHERE` clause to the `ON` clause might help (although it surpises me that the optimizer of MySQL does not do this already).

Comment: I suspect part of the problem with both mine and Oswalds solutions time wise is use of indexes for joins, with MySQL possibly ignoring the indexes if the range of items is very large (ie, covering most of the records on the table). It might be worth adding a column for the parent id in this case (could be updated from a trigger), which would massively help this query, while leaving your current LFT / RGT columns for queries where you need all the child / grandchild records of a parent.

Comment: Added separate index for each of ID, LFT, RGT. Nothing changed for both queries. In first query moved two conditions from `WHERE` to `ON` - still no changes. Running explain on first query: for `location` ID index is used limiting the set to 5 rows. For `descendant` TYPE index is used limiting set to 70k rows.

Comment: Running explain on second query: for `location` ID index is used (5 rows), for `child` TYPE index is used (70k rows), for `intermediate` out of possible LFT, RGT indices nothing is used (140k rows) with additional note `Range checked for each record (index map: 0x30); Not exists`

Comment: If you wonder I do have 5 rows per one ID value - we store location names in 5 languages, I omitted LANG column ('en', 'es' etc)

Comment: MySQL will only use one index on a table, hence it would choose one of either the index on ID, LFT or RGT. You probably need to have some index set up on multiple columns

Answer (score 1):

I would try something like these:-

```
SELECT b.*
FROM LOC_TABLE a
INNER JOIN LOC_TABLE b
ON a.LFT < b.LFT AND a.RGT > b.RGT
WHERE a.ID = 10
AND b.TYPE = 4
```

Simple JOIN.

For your second question, maybe something like this. Find the parent, then from that find all the records underneath of the right type. The find any parents of the same type of this child. If one is found then ignore.

```
SELECT b.*
FROM LOC_TABLE a
INNER JOIN LOC_TABLE b ON a.LFT < b.LFT AND a.RGT > b.RGT
LEFT JOIN LOC_TABLE c ON c.LFT > b.LFT AND c.RGT < b.RGT AND b.TYPE = c.TYPE
WHERE a.ID = 10
AND b.TYPE = 4
AND c.ID IS NULL
```

Comment: In first example I had to switch `a` and `b` in `WHERE` clause and it works, but as I mentioned already this type of query takes too much time to execute ~1.5 seconds, while I can fetch same info with two short queries (0.01 + 0.2 seconds). As for the second query it doesn't work out of the box, but I can see it is pretty much the same as in Oswald's answer. So it will take 3-6 seconds as well to fetch locations. Can we make it faster?

Comment: I was writing my answer at the same time as Oswald, and they are very similar. I will add an answer to Oswalds suggestion rather than confusing things with 2 very similar conversations.

Comment: By the way, think I made a mess of the < and > in the ON clauses, hence a minor issue. Fixed now.